# Does create-react-app-typescript polyfill lib es6?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I noticed that in the tsconfig for create-react-app-typescript, they have included a lib section for "es6" and "dom".

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
...
}
```

With most of the configuration of Creact React App being automagically done for us, I thought it'd be best to get clarification on the following.

By specifying lib es6 in tsconfig, to my understanding, the compiler will allow the code to compile, however no polyfills will be injected into the compiled output.

Does create-react-app-typescript take care of this, or do I need to bring my own polyfills?

Comment: You can import libraries like es6 and es2017 as per the [CompilerOptions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) and have them compile to es5, but only a [few polyfills](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/polyfills.js) are added by default, like "fetch" and "Object.assign".